# What am I doing wrong in this dcast (reshape2) function?

Tags: reshape2, dcast

So I have this table [image: football teams points by year]

and I need to arrange it by team as rows and year (2010 - 2015) as attributes, so Ive tried
with xtabs and table function, but I only get the count, instead of the points that the table contains.

Tried
dcast(EvoTeam, club_name~newdate, value.var = "total")
[image: output]

Although I define value.var as the score I am looking for, I still just get the frequency table.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Since there could be more than one value for each year, I get the error message

-Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length-

so I have to tell R what to do, in this case, I use the mean, so in the code I write
Evoteam.wide <- dcast(EvoTeam, club_name~newdate, value.var = 'total', mean)

It solved my problem